# I have an issue with my python script for merging pdf

Tags: python, pdf

I tried to create a python script for merging several pdf into one single pdf.
but sometimes the code works and sometimes it doesn't [because of that we can assume that the code doesn't work at all :( ].

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

import os


list_files=os.listdir("fusion/")   # we have to put all the pdf that we want to merge in this folder

nom_fichier =  input("Name the merged pdf (ne pas oublier le .pdf ) ")


"""
be sure that there is only pdf files in the directory
"""
pdfs = []

for file in list_files:
    i = 0

    if file[ len (file)-4 : len(file)] == ".pdf":
        pdfs.append(file)
        i+=1


print(pdfs)
#fusion des pdf déterminés à l'issu de l'étape précédente

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write(nom_fichier)
merger.close()
print("the pdf is ready")
```

we have to create a directory fusion in the current folder (where there is the script). In that directory there will be all the pdf to merge.

[what the bash show me when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NEEO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working directory is not "fusion". You seem to be running the script from the directory above "fusion". So the line

```
merger.append(pdf)
```

should be

```
merger.append("fusion/"+pdf)
```

to add back the fusion directory to the pdf file location path.

Comment: ok I did the change you suggest and now it works, thank you very much :)